# Disabled input text in twebbrowser delphi

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I would like to know how to add the property 'disabled' to a text type field in a web page in a TWebbrowser with delphi.
I use this code but neither the property 'Disabled' nor 'ReadOnly' have any effect on the field even though the value is modified.
Thank you for your help and your advice

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  col: IHTMLElementCollection;
  el: IHTMLInputElement;
begin
  col := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementsByName('input_name');
  if col.length <> 0 then
  begin
    el := col.item(0, 0) as IHTMLInputElement;
    el.value := 'new_value';
    el.disabled := True;
    el.readOnly := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: In fact disabled/readonly works but when i click on the field, the default value appears and i would like see only my new value...

Comment: please make a complete sample. In which IE mode are you running (TWebbrowser runs in IE7 mode by default)

Comment: Thx
The IE Mode is IE 11
It's the full sample. The initial HTML is <input name="input_name" value="ABC">
So the input form value is changed to 'new_value' but when i click on it in the TWebbrowser, on this input field, the value return to ABC...